# URL Access to static HTML pages - in Parse.com platform before login

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I’m new to parse and was trying to create a simple web app with it using static HTML pages, CSS, and JS
I’ve used cloud functions also for a few tasks.

The thing is that I’ve created a login page and a function that checks if the user is logged into the web app with JS client-side and it looks like this:

```
function CheckUserLogin(){ 
   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
   if (currentUser) {
    //do nothing
   } else {
    //rediect user to login html page
    window.location.href = “loginpage.html”
  }
}
```

The thing is that if the user navigates to the /Home.html page via browser URL he can see the page for a few seconds until js checks if he logged in and redirects the user out to the login page.
I guess that’s not so secure…

Any idea how to get a solution for achieving this task via js or parse.com cloud functions more secure?

Comment: which server you are using to serve Home.html? Parse? Can you share the server function which is returning Home.html?

Comment: The server i'm using is Linux\ubuntu 18 on a docker with parse server installed on it  - "Home.html" file is placed within the "Public" folder located in the main folder of the app. the express.js function calling it located in the "index.js" file in the parse server  - app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/home.html'));

});  (all the files and folders under the "public" folder are wide open to the world...)

Comment: So the idea is instead of checking user login on the frontend, check it before hand on the server side before returning Home.html. Because this kind of things should be done on the server side, frontend will always be too late for this kind of security.

Comment: any idea how should I accomplish this using parse server?

Comment: Can you share the exact file in which you are adding this route, which returns Home.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following two things to achieve this:

First you need to override Parse login with your own custom login, you can do something like this:

```
// this will add sessionToken in a cookie, which can be later used to check if your user is logged in or not
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function(user) {
        var val = JSON.stringify({sessionToken: user.getSessionToken()});
        var opts = {path: '/', httpOnly: true};
        res.cookie('parse.session', val, opts);
        res.redirect('/');
    }).then(null, function(error) {
        res.clearCookie('parse.session');
        res.render('pages/login', { flash: error.message });
    });
});
```

Now you need to add a middleware to get this user from the cookie:

```
// Middleware adding current user to `req.user` or redirecting to login if not logged in
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var cookie = null;
    new Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
        cookie = JSON.parse(req.cookies['parse.session']);
        return Parse._request('GET', 'users/me', {}, {sessionToken: cookie.sessionToken});
    }).then(function (userData) {
        userData.sessionToken = cookie.sessionToken;
        req.user = Parse.Object.fromJSON(userData);
        next();
    }).then(null, function () {
        res.clearCookie('parse.session');
        return res.redirect('/login');
    });
});
```

Now you can safely assume that if user reached Home.html, it will be a logged in user. Still I would not suggest putting HTML files in public folder, instead use a template engine.

Comment: Can you please explain exact issue you are facing with this solution?